# INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, forms, xamarin

Hello everybody I'm developing this cross application app in Xamarin form, with the new update I keep getting this error the I try to compile my android app in release mode:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:  Deployment failed
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010: Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/it.HangoverApp.Hangover-u52elz30u_htRlO7sbz98A==: Package /data/app/it.HangoverApp.Hangover-u52elz30u_htRlO7sbz98A==/base.apk code is missing]
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess (System.String output, System.String packageName) [0x00152] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/Internal/AdbOutputParsing.cs:341 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice+<>c__DisplayClass95_0.<InstallPackage>b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] t) [0x00016] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/AndroidDevice.cs:753 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1[TAntecedentResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in <f9d1b832704f410aa8ec771f4fe80552>:0 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010: 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.PushAndInstallPackage (Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice device, System.String apkFile, System.String packageName, System.Boolean reinstall, Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbProgressReporter notifyProgress, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00189] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:187 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.PushAndInstallPackage (Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice device, System.String apkFile, System.String packageName, System.Boolean reinstall, Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbProgressReporter notifyProgress, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x003df] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:203 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.InstallPackage () [0x003be] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:433 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.RunAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x003ae] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:217 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.RunLoggedAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x0002f] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:119 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010: Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/it.HangoverApp.Hangover-u52elz30u_htRlO7sbz98A==: Package /data/app/it.HangoverApp.Hangover-u52elz30u_htRlO7sbz98A==/base.apk code is missing]
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess (System.String output, System.String packageName) [0x00152] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/Internal/AdbOutputParsing.cs:341 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice+<>c__DisplayClass95_0.<InstallPackage>b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] t) [0x00016] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/AndroidDevice.cs:753 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1[TAntecedentResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in <f9d1b832704f410aa8ec771f4fe80552>:0 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010: 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.PushAndInstallPackage (Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice device, System.String apkFile, System.String packageName, System.Boolean reinstall, Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbProgressReporter notifyProgress, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00189] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:187 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.PushAndInstallPackage (Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice device, System.String apkFile, System.String packageName, System.Boolean reinstall, Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbProgressReporter notifyProgress, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x003df] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:203 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.InstallPackage () [0x003be] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:433 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.RunAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x003ae] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:217 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(612,2): error ADB0010:   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.RunLoggedAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x0002f] in /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:119
```

Any suggestion on how to fix it? Thanks.

Visual Studio Version:8.5.1 (Build 42)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable Multi-Dex in project settings and set d8 as dex compiler. Also, check for updates for Android SDK.

P.S. Cleaning/deleting content of both /bin and /obj may be required.

Comment: Thanks a lot! after doing what you said and deleting src and obj, worked great!

Comment: Glad to help! Had a same problem few days ago. Click on my answer as "Accepted" so others can quickly find the solution.